# Kernel panic inside mod_timer()

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am writing a program which uses multiple timers. For every 5 seconds, they will use one same netlink to communicate with userspace.

To be more specifically, every 5 seconds each timer will call a `func()`, the `func()` will do lock, sending something, unlock, and:

```
delay_us(200);        
if(!timer_pending(&timer1)){
    mod_timer(&timer1, jiffies+RTL_SECONDS_TO_JIFFIES(5));
}
```

The strange thing is in very few occasion, the system will crash inside `mod_timer()`, I disassembly and find it crash at `tne  zero,v0,0xc`

The piece of code (MIPS instructions) is below:

```
    /*
     * This is a common optimization triggered by the
     * networking code - if the timer is re-modified
     * to be the same thing then just return:
     */
    if (timer_pending(timer) && timer->expires == expires)
800216bc:   8e020000    lw  v0,0(s0)
800216c0:   50400005    beqzl   v0,800216d8 <mod_timer+0x98>
800216c4:   8e020010    lw  v0,16(s0)
800216c8:   8e020008    lw  v0,8(s0)
800216cc:   10510042    beq v0,s1,800217d8 <mod_timer+0x198>
800216d0:   24130001    li  s3,1
800216d4:   8e020010    lw  v0,16(s0)
800216d8:   2c420001    sltiu   v0,v0,1
800216dc:   00020336    tne zero,v0,0xc
```

I am in great pain to debug. I doubt timer race but technically if so, crash should not inside `mod_timer()` right? It looks very likely some kind of racing happen but it's beyond my knowledge. Any debug suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT :I just add some important dump message below：

```
Call Trace:
[<800243a4>] mod_timer+0x9c/0x1b8
[<8002399c>] call_timer_fn+0x20/0x88
[<80023bd0>] run_timer_softirq+0x1cc/0x244
[<8001de80>] __do_softirq+0x118/0x218
[<8001e05c>] do_softirq+0x58/0x78
[<8001e0e0>] irq_exit+0x64/0x80
[<8000044c>] ret_from_irq+0x0/0x4
[<800036cc>] __copy_user_common+0x44/0x2b8
[<8006701c>] file_read_actor+0x9c/0x114
[<8006a47c>] generic_file_aio_read+0x4f4/0x7f4
[<80092f00>] do_sync_read+0x90/0xd4
[<80093fc8>] vfs_read+0xb0/0x158
[<80094170>] SyS_read+0x60/0x9c
[<800017b0>] stack_done+0x20/0x40


Code: 24130001  8e020010  2c420001 <00020336> 02002021  0c008f12  27a50010  8e030000  10600015
```

EDIT:The callback function is like:

```
void send_info(unsigned long task_priv)
{
    unsigned long flags;

    struct target_priv *priv = (struct target_priv *)task_priv;

    SMP_LOCK(flags);

    construct_netlink_send(priv);

    SMP_UNLOCK(flags);

    delay_us(200);

    if ((!strcmp(priv->name, "timer0")) && (!timer_pending(&priv->timer0))){
                mod_timer(&priv->timer0, jiffies+SECONDS_TO_JIFFIES(5));
                    return;
            }
    ...//do same for the rest 9 timers
}
```

Comment: What is `delay_us`? There is no such function in Linux kernel, do you mean `udelay()`? As for error debugging: if this is bug in `mod_timer`, you should report it, not to post here. But most likely it is a bug in your code which (probably, because of race) *corrupts* timer structure. There is almost *indefinite number* of ways to corrupt some internal structure being in Linux kernel, so without the full code we unlikely can help you. As for possibly direction to debug - determine (using crash report) what **exact** parameter is wrong in the given instruction, and try to trace it in the code.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, thanks for your reply, the other parts of code is too long and impossible to post(and probably unrelated). delay_us is udelay() and I kind of encapsulated it. I know find exactly solution here is impossible, so any guessing is greatly helping. And technically can multiple timer share same netlink?

Comment: `can multiple timer share same netlink?` - Timer's function may do everything which is allowed in atomic context. As functions for different timers may run in parallel, you need appropriate synchronization for access same objects inside them. `any guessing is greatly helping.` - Guessing what can be wrong with the code you don't show? This is not how Stack Overflow works. Not every programming problem should be asked here, sometimes you need just to debug your code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Alright I will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some advice for you do debug this problems.

1. reduce your timer count, make sure every thing is OK when has only one timer.
2. please attach some panic info, and maybe I can find some useful info to help you solve the problem.
3. I am not sure if the "delay_us(200);" may cause the problem. the timer callback is in the soft-interrupt content, and it's cannot be block. So, the lock you have used also need to check if it may block the content.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks for your suggestions! I just added some messages.

Comment: @MichaelPeng, can you attach the code of the callback.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, just added. I googled your third suggestion about delay and find it do look like a probably cause.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, sorry for the late reply. The root cause I found afterwards is when the application close, timers are accidentally not properly deleted. The next time when application runs, it will add timers again and cause problems. By the way, my hometown is also in Wuhan, nice to meet u here lol.

Comment: @MichaelPeng, glad to meet u here to. And the most glad thing is your hometown is also WuHan, maybe we have chance to see each other.

Comment: Surly will, homie. Currently I work at Singapore, hopefully we can meet each other in the future.

Answer (score 0):

this code may cause problem:

```
if ((!strcmp(priv->name, "timer0")) && (!timer_pending(&priv->timer0))){
            mod_timer(&priv->timer0, jiffies+SECONDS_TO_JIFFIES(5));
                return;
        }
```

You cannot modify the other timer in the callback. It's may destruct the timer's link.

Comment: Hey Jimmy, although every timer all use this function but they have different name(priv->name), so they are only able to modify their own timer. You may see the comment in the end of code, its grey and not easy to see..

Comment: OK, can you remove the "delay_us(200);", and check if the problem still existed. Or increase the time, such as "delay_us(2000);" to check if the problem occur absolutely.